# MySQL Group By using MAX wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, database, group-by

I am trying to get a users most current messages for each conversation. However my group by query doesnt seem to be bringing the correct rows back. Here is my data:

```
ID | MESSAGE | RELATED_ID | DATE_SENT
 2 | Hi      |     2      | 2013-02-21 16:03:00
 3 | Hii     |     2      | 2013-02-21 16:04:00
 4 | Hiii    |     2      | 2013-02-21 16:05:00
 5 | Hiiii   |     2      | 2013-02-21 16:06:00
 6 | Bye     |     6      | 2013-02-21 16:03:01
 7 | Byee    |     6      | 2013-02-21 16:04:01
 8 | Byeee   |     6      | 2013-02-21 16:05:01
 9 | Again   |     9      | 2013-02-21 16:03:02
 10| Againn  |     9      | 2013-02-21 16:04:02
```

The result i am looking for is:

```
ID | MESSAGE | RELATED_ID | DATE_SENT
 5 | Hiiii   |     2      | 2013-02-21 16:06:00
 8 | Byeee   |     6      | 2013-02-21 16:05:01
 10| Againn  |     9      | 2013-02-21 16:04:02
```

My current query is:

```
 SELECT MAX(ID), Message, Date_Sent, related_id FROM MESSAGES GROUP BY RELATED_ID LIMIT 0,100
```

The result that I get is:

```
ID | MESSAGE | RELATED_ID | DATE_SENT
 5 | Hi      |     2      | 2013-02-21 16:03:00
 8 | Bye     |     6      | 2013-02-21 16:03:01
 10| Again   |     9      | 2013-02-21 16:03:02
```

It seems to be getting the correct ID but not the correct data for that ID.

I would appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: GROUP BY return first matching record.

Comment: Arghh!  Another unsuspecting new SQLer trapped by MySQL's confusing nonstandard extension to GROUP BY.  Advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic, but this is *not* advanced technology. Please read this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to use a subquery to select the `max(id)` for each `related_id` and then join that to your table:

```
select m1.id,
  m1.message,
  m1.related_id,
  m1.date_sent
from messages m1
inner join
(
  select max(id) MaxId, related_id
  from messages
  group by related_id
) m2
  on m1.id = m2.MaxId
  and m1.related_id = m2.related_id
LIMIT 0,100
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50a15/2). Doing it this way will make sure that you return the correct values for the other columns in the `SELECT` list. When you do not `GROUP BY` or aggregate all the items in the `SELECT` list, MySQL chooses the values for the other columns and you might get unexpected results. (See [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html))

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

Comment: +1 for the quote from the documentation for the MySQL nonstandard extension misfeature.

Comment: +1 To disable the misfeature you can set `Server Mode` [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Answer (score -2):

maybe it should be something like this

replace `MAX(ID)` with `MAX(Date_Sent)`

Comment: OP's problem is that he selects ungrouped and unaggregated columns in a query using group by clause. While this is forbidden in standard SQL (for good reasons), MySQL permits this and often results in unexpected and unpredictable results like here. In MySQL data from the first record is returned which is DB-Interna you should not rely on. Said this there is no benefit but great potential for failure.